# How to identify an array defined in a shared library?

Tags: shared-libraries, objdump, binutils, nm, readelf

I'm dealing with an old proprietary shared library -- no source code.

The binary contains lots of symbols (thousands), among them an array of character strings I need (several hundred strings). I know, it is there, because `strings(1)` lists them all -- in sequence. Unfortunately, the header files accompanying the library do not declare this list...

How do I find out, which symbol in the library refers to the array? I'd then add my own declaration and be able to access it from my code...

Answer (score 1):

**The easy way...**

Try the `find` command in `gdb`.

For example, I'll guess that the strings are in the `.rodata` section of the shared library, so we'll use `info target` to find the address bounds of that section, and do our search in that range:

```
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401136
Starting program: /scratch/a.out 
Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401136 in main ()
(gdb) info target
    ...
    0x00007f5049f0c000 - 0x00007f5049f0c020 is .rodata in ./lib.so
    ...
(gdb) find 0x00007f5049f0c000,0x00007f5049f0c020,"test string"
0x7f5049f0c000 <foo1>
0x7f5049f0c014
2 patterns found.
```

That should work if your strings were declared as initialized char arrays, like

```
static const char foo1[] = "test string";
```

If they were declared as pointers, like

```
static const char *foo2 = "another test string";
```

it's going to be a bit harder. The string itself won't be labeled, and the symbol you're looking for will be a pointer to that string. You'll then need to use the `find` command again to search for that pointer value, which I'll guess is in the `.data` section.

```
(gdb) find 0x00007f5049f0c000,0x00007f5049f0c020,"another test string"
0x7f5049f0c00c
1 pattern found.
(gdb) info target
    ...
    0x00007f5049f0e018 - 0x00007f5049f0e028 is .data in ./foo.so
    ...
(gdb) find 0x00007f5049f0e018,0x00007f5049f0e028,0x7f5049f0c00c
0x7f5049f0e020 <foo2>
1 pattern found.
```

**The learning experience...**

Use `strings --radix=x`, and find your string. The offset within the file will be listed (in hex); e.g.:

```
$ strings --radix=x lib.so | grep "test string" 
5ad740 test string
```

Now you need to convert that file offset to a virtual address.

Use `readelf -lW` to list the segments of the library; you'll see something like this:

```
$ readelf -lW lib.so | grep -e Type -e LOAD
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x004dc0 0x004dc0 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x005000 0x0000000000405000 0x0000000000405000 0x53a989 0x53a989 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x540000 0x0000000000940000 0x0000000000940000 0x28f7c2 0x28f7c2 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x7cfc70 0x0000000000bd0c70 0x0000000000bd0c70 0x0014b0 0x00d518 RW  0x1000
```

You're interested in the `Offset`, `VirtAddr`, and `FileSiz` columns. Find the LOAD segment that contains your file offset `X`, where `Offset <= X < Offset + FileSiz`. In this example, the offset 0x5ad740 is in the third segment (starting at offset 0x540000). Convert your offset to a virtual address by subtracting the starting offset of the segment and adding the starting virtual address of the segment:

```
offset - starting offset + starting virtual address = virtual address
0x5ad740 - 0x540000 + 0x940000 = 0x9ad740
```

Now use `nm -n` to scan the symbol table in address order. If you're lucky, you'll find an exact match:

```
$ nm -n lib.so | grep 9ad740
00000000009ad740 R foo1
```

Otherwise, you'll need to look for the closest symbol with a lower address. That should be it, *if the strings were declared as arrays*.

If the strings were declared as pointers, those pointers will need dynamic relocations (we *are* looking at a shared library, right?) -- most likely `R_xxx_RELATIVE` relocations. Look for a RELATIVE relocation whose addend matches your string's virtual address:

```
$ readelf -rW lib.so
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0xc00000 contains 2 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000c00018  0000000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                      9ad740
```

That shows that your pointer is at 0xc00018. Using `nm` again, you can find the symbol for that virtual address:

```
$ nm -n lib.so | grep c00018
0000000000c00018 R foo2
```

Comment: A very informative answer for someone with such a low number of points :) You should post more, thank you very much!